# Transition to iOS 7: correct viewport setting for jQuery/iPhone Webapps viewed on iPads

Tags: ios, ipad, jquery-mobile, uiwebview, ios7

We have an app with essentially one UIWebView which is set to "iPhone App" in XCode.

Until now all worked fine, but using the iOS 7 iPad Simulator the App now appears in "Full Screen" immediately, which would not be the problem, but the WebView also appears to be zoomed in.

I only see the upper right 1/4 of the website thats loaded and have to scroll to see the rest.

We use jQuery mobile 1.3.1 in the application.

**edit**

I found the error. It seems the semantics of the viewport meta-element changed between iOS versions.

Changing

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

worked for me, but I am unsure if this is the way to go since the [jQuery Mobile Demo](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/) Page does set the with to the device-with. When I load the Demo-Page from my UIWebView I get the same effect.

Is there any information on "the right way" to set the viewport, especially since the demo page uses width=device-width

Comment: Good one ! This solved it for me as well. You should make it as an answer.

Comment: Good to know but I'd like to understand why this is the case. I'll put this in as an answer if nobody has a good explanation in a week or so.

Comment: It`s solution only for iphone app on ipad, on others devices it breaks webpage width.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On iOS 7 it has been changed the way of interpreting the vieport meta tag.
Here you can find an explanation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-7.0/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013202-CH1-SW75 .

> Previously, when the viewport parameters were modified, the old parameters were never discarded.
>   This caused the viewport parameters to be additive.
>
> For example, if you started with width=device-width and then changed
>   it to initial-scale=1.0, you ended up with a computed viewport of
>   width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0.
>
> In iOS 7, this has been addressed. Now you end up with with a computed
>   viewport of initial-scale=1.0.

Thw question now is: how this will affect the layout on iOS6< and on Android devices ?

Comment: I'd like to repeat: >>hw question now is: how this will affect the layout on iOS6< and on Android devices<< ? This restates the question!

Answer (score 4):

I had an iPhone app that would only "break" on an iOS7 iPad. Removing "width=device-width" from the viewport meta tag fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

i used your answer but it doesnt solve all of my problems. 
The initial size remains with ipad's width instead of iphone's.

Also when i try to write on a text the screen zoom itselfs to fill the textbox and only when i press done the screen re-sizes to its proper iphone's size.

I still need a proper solution for this.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? we're suffering from the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is the best, you can have a try，Should be compatible with ios5/ios6/ios7 including android

code:

```
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=2.0" name="viewport" />
```

iOS7 uiwebview may want to change the height：

code:

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
if (version >= 7.0)
{
    self.webView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
}
else
{
    self.webView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height-20);
}
```

Comment: Where did you add this at? the code change not the meta.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with a phonegap and removing device-width didn't solve the problem for me.

I had to modify Classes/MainViewController.m

I modified:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

To be:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView {

    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    if (version >= 7.0)
    {

        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width, initial-scale=.42 user-scalable=no');$('body').animate({'opacity':1},300)"];
    }

    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

*** UPDATE ***

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    // iPhone app zoom on iPad with iOS 7 fix

    float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

    if (version >= 7.0)
    {

        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"if(!(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) && !(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {$('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width, initial-scale=.42 user-scalable=no');}"];
    }

    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$('body').animate({'opacity':1},300)"];

    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

I moved the fade in code outside of the if statement as < iOS7 would remain at opacity 0 otherwise

*** END UPDATE ***

I used the "version" variable and if statement to target iOS 7. Thanks @leetvin

Then reduced the scale from being zoomed in

Initially there was a jump between the zoomed in view and the scaled down view so i set opacity of body to 0 in css and animated/faded in after the resize

Comment: I also used this fix for the status bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209781/ios-7-status-bar-with-phonegap