# iOS 7 viewport meta tag change

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile-safari

Has anyone had issues with the viewport tag since the iOS7 update? I have a few sites that now have this white margin on the right side. I adjusted the initial scale to 0.1 and it fit the iPhone just fine but on an iPad 3 it was tiny, which makes sense given the low scale.

I didn't have this issue until the update and I can't find any documentation out there regarding any changes to how safari handles the viewport meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like iOS 7 is a bit buggy using meta description.
I sometimes need to reload me website to be displayed all right.

Maybe Apple will fix that with iOS 7.1. There are a few other bugs as well.

Comment: at this point i'm thinking it's better just to leave the viewport tag out completely and have the right margin. The only other option I can think of is adding a ton of conditional meta tags which is not appealing in the least bit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple viewport tags? If so, combine them into a single tag, per [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19088404).