# How to remove status bar in cordova 2.9.0 for IOS 7?

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am making phonegap app for ios and getting issue of status bar hidden in cordova 2.9.0 for ios 7. Is any body know how fix this issue through out the app? Please help me to fix this bug.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 Status bar with Phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209781/ios-7-status-bar-with-phonegap)

Answer (score 2):

Open Project in xcode 
first select checkbox ( hide during application launch ) under status bar style - general project settings in xcode

[image]

select projectname-info.plist  (Resources section in xcode)

[image]

and add key "View controller-based status bar appearance"  and value "NO"

[image]