# Opening and closing inappbrowser brings a white bar at bottom phonegap+sencha in ios 7

Tags: ios, extjs, cordova, ios7, touch

Am using sencha touch 2.2.1 and phonegap 2.9

I am using inappbrowser to show an external webpage. (eg: facebook login)

It opens and closes normally but after inappbrowser is closed, it brings a white bar at bottom of the screen and each time inappbrowser is opened and closed, it grows to top..

Issue is noted only in ios 7..

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that i had set 20px margin to prevent status bar from overlapping app.. I was been using answers from [iOS 7 Status bar with Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209781/ios-7-status-bar-with-phonegap)..

Now i removed that code and completely hidden the status bar.. And the issue also disappeared.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was having the same problem using phonegap 3.5 and jquery mobile 1.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7 Status bar issue, please install phonegap plugin by running command

```
$ phonegap plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin
```

then add below line to config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" />
```

It will not interfere with inappbrowser.