# Cordova/PhoneGap iOS: WebView becoming shorter after taking a picture or opening InAppBrowser

Tags: ios, cordova, webview

When I take a picture with Camera plugin, the whole WebView becomes shorter. It's like the screen is being eaten from bottom for the height of the status bar - 20px. It doesn't have to do with taking a picture at all, it also happens if I only open gallery and then close it. The same thing happens if I open InAppBrowser and then close it. Here is an example:

[image: This is how it looks before choosing a photo]

This is how it looks before choosing a photo

[image: Then the photo choosing dialog appears (doesn't matter if it's emulator, it behaves the same on the real device)]

Then the photo choosing dialog appears (doesn't matter if it's emulator, it behaves the same on the real device)

[image: And then this happens when I close the dialog - look at the bottom of the screen]

And then this happens when I close the dialog - look at the bottom of the screen

[image: And if I continue to add photos, each time the screen gets 'eaten' by 20px]

And if I continue to add photos, each time the screen gets 'eaten' by 20px

I found out that the window.innerHeight is getting reduced by 20px, so it has something to do with the status bar. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon the answer in another thread. Here it is:

In MainViewController.h:

```
@interface MainViewController : CDVViewController
@property (atomic) BOOL viewSizeChanged;
@end
```

In MainViewController.m:

```
@implementation MainViewController

@synthesize viewSizeChanged;

[...]

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // On init, size has not yet been changed
        self.viewSizeChanged = NO;
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandDelegateImpl used
        // _commandDelegate = [[MainCommandDelegate alloc] initWithViewController:self];
        // Uncomment to override the CDVCommandQueue used
        // _commandQueue = [[MainCommandQueue alloc] initWithViewController:self];
    }
    return self;
}

[...]

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // View defaults to full size.  If you want to customize the view's size, or its subviews (e.g. webView),
    // you can do so here.
    // Lower screen 20px on ios 7 if not already done
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7 && !self.viewSizeChanged) {
        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
        viewBounds.origin.y = 20;
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 20;
        self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
        self.viewSizeChanged = YES;
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19407903/1555838