# Why does my Cordova WebView have an extra 20px of scrolling?

Tags: ios, cordova, ios6, scroll, statusbar

I am building a Cordova app, and I'm testing it on my iOS 6 device (iPod Touch w/ iOS 6.1.6).  For some reason, the WebView is scrollable with an extra 20px, seemingly making up for the 20px status bar at the top of the screen.  This sometimes causes the scrollable WebView to take focus, essentially causing "nothing" to scroll in the eyes of the user, rather than allowing scrollable `div`s in my app to scroll.  I have tried numerous fixes pertaining to config.xml changes, plugins, etc, but nothing makes a difference, which I've outlined below.

1. Tried [manually hiding the status bar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/blob/master/doc/index.md#statusbarhide), with no effect.

   ```
   // config.xml:
   <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" version="0.1.7" />

   <feature name="StatusBar">
     <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" />
   </feature>

   // index.js (ondeviceready):
   window.StatusBar && window.StatusBar.hide();
   ```
2. Tried forcing the status bar to overlay the webview, essentially making the app a full 480px tall (instead of 460px):

   ```
   // config.xml:
   <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" version="0.1.7" />

   <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
   ```
3. Tried forcing the status bar to [*not* overlay the webview](http://devgirl.org/2014/07/31/phonegap-developers-guid/):

   ```
   // config.xml:
   <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" version="0.1.7" />

   <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
   <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
   <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
   ```
4. Tried offsetting the body's margin-top by 20px, which just adds an extra 20px of dead whitespace:

   ```
   // index.css:
   body {
     margin-top: 20px;
   }
   ```
5. Tried setting the app to [fullscreen](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File_global_preferences), which literally has no effect on the app whatsoever:

   ```
   // config.xml:
   <preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
   ```
6. I even used Safari inspector to delete the `body` DOM node altogether, and it still scrolls 20px, telling me that it has nothing to do with the HTML so much as Cordova's implementation of the WebView.

Does anyone have a solution for this?  I can't be the only one out there encountering this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Figured it out after almost 8 hours of tinkering.  Had to replace the `meta` viewport setting from this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,
        maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width,
        height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,
        maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

It seems that `height=device-height` was taking the full device height into account, including the status bar.  I did see a way to work around this in JavaScript for those who are interested, which is covered by [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19407903/107277).  I don't see any drawback to removing altogether though (for a Cordova app targeting iOS 6+).

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this on deviceready?

```
window.StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
```

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar/blob/master/doc/index.md

Comment: This theoretically should have the same effect as `<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />`.  Just gave it a shot, and there's no difference in scrolling.

Comment: Sorry man! Good luck, upvoted this question as I am sure I will have the same issue in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Ionic + AngularJs

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function ($rootScope, $state) {
            //set status bar 
            $cordovaStatusbar.styleHex('#637386');
            $cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(true);

            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
                function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    //for me was helpful this call
                    $cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(true);

                });
}])
```

Comment: I wasn't using these technologies in my project, but I'm sure this will help someone who comes across this question. :)  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: does not answer OP