# Ionic app pages are longer than viewport therefore page can be scrolled a bit hiding the header under the status bar

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I know this question has been asked and answered before. For example: [Why does my Cordova WebView have an extra 20px of scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295208/why-does-my-cordova-webview-have-an-extra-20px-of-scrolling)

However the solutions offered seemed to have worked on older version and they do not work now. I have tried setting the app to full screen, and while the app does go into full screen mode, the pages still are a bit longer, so even then you can scroll it a bit.

This problem is making the app look like a website instead of a native app which is horrible.

Comment: I would recommend you to include additional details for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

In my Ionic Android app with nav bar at the top and content below it, I have this in index.html (I'm including the ion-tabs and the template for the ion-nav-view directive inline for clarity):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab title="Broadcast" icon-off="ion-ios-mic-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-mic" class="tab-icon" href="#/tab/broadcast">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-broadcast"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-nav-view>
    <ion-view view-title="BROADCAST">
        <ion-content>
            <div class="list">
                <div class="item item-body">
                    <p>Here is my stuff</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
</ion-nav-view>
```

This layout does not give me any overscroll issues, how about you?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by tweaking some of the values in the ionic.css file, namely .has-header, .has-subheader and .has-tabs-tops
I also changed the height of the .view-container to 96% instead of 100% and that helped.

This wasn't perfect ...

In any case I am not in need of this anymore since I decided to change the app a bit and started using a Side Menu for navigation instead of tabs ...