# Can I publish with Xcode 6 to AppStore a Phonegap app that's developed with 2.5.0 Cordova Version

Tags: ios, cordova, ios8, xcode6.1

I have an app developed with Cordova/Phonegap I need to upload to App Store.

The project uses 'cordova 2.5.0' and we would like to upload it to AppStore with Xcode 6. The app just shows data information from web services, it doesn't access to the native features of the iOS SDK, like camera, gps ..

Can I upload it directly, or I have to upgrade the project to iOS 3.7.0 and Cordova 4.0.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no explicit need to upgrade your project to the latest version of Cordova in order to upload it to the App Store - Apple won't reject it on this basis. So long as your app complies with the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), it won't be a problem.

Having said that, there are some potential issues with using an old version of Cordova with more recent versions of iOS, such as the [overlapping status bar issue in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209781/ios-7-status-bar-with-phonegap), but nothing that can't be resolved.

If you've tested your app on iOS devices running the latest version of iOS and it looks/works fine, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: No probs :-) I speak from experience as I have an app which is built with cordova 2.9.0 [currently in the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iwalk-north-cornwall/id739048330?ls=1&mt=8). The status bar issue in iOS7 was the only problem I encountered. The app now works fine in iOS 7 & 8.x and uses multiple sensors from the device (GPS, compass, etc.). Yours sounds much simpler in terms of access to native features, so it should be fine.

Comment: That helps to my problem, because I wasn't sure and in the Cordova documentation they don't dig into it. I'll fix the same problem that the app has with the status bar. Cheers mate