# UIWebView loads page with 20 pixel gap in portrait

Tags: uiwebview, ios8

I have a `UIWebView` to load certain pages.In iOS 8 it loads page with 20 pixel gap from top specially in portrait mode,in landscape mode it is fine.
How to handle the gap in portrait?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place following code in your viewWillAppear :

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
        viewBounds.origin.y = 20;
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 20;
        self.webView.frame = viewBounds;
    }
```

Check this for more information : [iOS 7 Status bar with Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209781/ios-7-status-bar-with-phonegap)

Comment: This means there is no direct way to achieve this other than changing frames.